# What does it mean to declare struct with var?

Tags: go

I found the `struct` is defined in the source code of a package like this:

```golang
var resp struct {
    CreateTodo struct{ ID string }
}
```

I always define the struct like this:

```golang
type resp struct {
    CreateTodo struct{ ID string }
}
```

I have never seen this. After searching, I only found a [doc](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#2) about it. But there is no explanation of its meaning.
So, what's the difference between `type xxx struct {}` and `var xxx struct {}`? When and how should I use `var xxx struct {}`? Thanks.

Comment: `type xxx` declares a new type, `var xxx` declares a new variable.

Comment: @zerkms I got it. It's declare a variable `resp` which type is a anonymous struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declares a variable `resp` whose type is the (anonymous) struct.

Comment: I got it. It's same like `var resp string`, But here the `resp`'s type is the (anonymous) struct.

Comment: More info: https://talks.golang.org/2015/tricks.slide#6